# Python3 returning unexpected Unicode/ASCII

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

Environment:  Python 3.6, bs4

I am using the following code to 'webscrape' data from a local html file.  The code is generally returning data as expected except instead of returning `ü` my code is returning `Ã¼`.

I am saving the recovered data to a UTF-8 .csv file.  The `Ã¼` character is being displayed onto the console and into the .csv file.  I am unsure where the problem lies.  Is this a Unicode/charmap issue?  My code?  Or something else?

I would like the correct character to be returned, in this case `ü`

My code snippet...

````
#   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50308840/error-extracting-text-from-website-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attr
    try:
        description_elemt = result.find("div", attrs = {'class':'product-desc'}).get_text(strip=True)
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()  #  debug info to console only
        description_elemt = 'No data given'
    #   replace 'Length' with 'length', this leaves 'Blade length: xxx mm' as one cell/element
    #   ref chapter 2.5, p45, Python Cookbook, 9781449340377
    description_elemt = description_elemt.replace('Length', 'length')
    description_elem = re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', description_elemt)
    #   gather the line items into one row ,separated by ,
    description_elem = ','.join(description_elem)```

Thanks guys.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything in your example that displays the text on your console. You should also not be using `','.join(description_elem)` to construct a CSV line. Note that the Unicode character `ü` is `\xC3\xBC` encoded as UTF-8. And in the ISO 8859-13 encoding  `\xC3` is `Ã` and `\xBC` is `¼`. Other ISO 8859 encodings share one or both of those codepoint to glyph mappings. What this tells me is that the input you're parsing is not UTF-8, your program is not using a UTF-8 encoding, or you're looking at the output of your program using a non-UTF-8 locale. In other words, the problem is your code or the locale of your terminal emulator and/or shell.

Comment: Hi Kurtis,  Can you please explain what you mean by "You should also not be using ','.join(description_elem) to construct a CSV line."  Can you give an example, please?

Comment: @TommyGibbons, You should be using the `csv` package to read/write CSV content rather than your hand-written solution. You simple approach might work for your specific case. But as soon as the data contains commas, whitespace, or quote marks your solution won't produce valid CSV output.

Comment: @ Kurtis Rader,  I marked your answer as correct.  It was my code as you suggested.  Could I ask you, Kurtis, as I know very little, if you could give me a pointer as to what you mean by "the csv package to read/write CSV content", please

Comment: @TommyGibbons, I'm referring to the module documented by `pydoc csv` and at https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html. It's been part of the python stdlib as long as I can recall; at least back to python 2.6.